# SQL - is developing queries based on nonexistent data possible?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

Is it possible to develop a query from nonexistent data? for example, I have this schema :

-- ZIP code database

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE city (

city_id INT,
city_name VARCHAR(80),
city_county VARCHAR(80),
city_state VARCHAR(5),
city_country VARCHAR(5),
city_region VARCHAR(5),
longitude INT,
latitude INT,
timezone varchar(80),
PRIMARY KEY (city_id)
);

CREATE TABLE zipcode (

zipcode CHAR(5),
ziptype VARCHAR(36),
active  BOOLEAN,
primary_city_id INT NOT NULL,
notes   TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (zipcode),
FOREIGN KEY (primary_city_id) REFERENCES city(city_id)
);

CREATE TABLE acceptable (

zipcode CHAR(5),
city_id INT,
acceptable BOOLEAN,
PRIMARY KEY (zipcode, city_id),
FOREIGN KEY (zipcode) REFERENCES zipcode(zipcode),
FOREIGN KEY (city_id) REFERENCES city(city_id)
);

CREATE TABLE zip_areacode (

zipcode CHAR(5),
areacode VARCHAR(5),
PRIMARY KEY (zipcode, areacode),
FOREIGN KEY (zipcode) REFERENCES zipcode(zipcode),
FOREIGN KEY (areacode) REFERENCES areacode(prefix)
);
COMMIT;
```

//from here, would I be able to filter out results by the zip code with the highest population? This isn't possible, right? I don't see any data regarding population

Comment: You can develop a query against empty tables, or just descriptions of tables. You just can't test it very usefully until you have data - either the real data, or dummy data. In this case though I don't see any description of the population information, any table definition for it, or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cant. Because you have no information about population. Thus your queries will be on non existent relations. That's not possible.

You can create temporary tables (relations) if you want. And fill it with random data. But I don't think you'll find out something useful.